# How to attach invoice pdf generate and send with custom email in magento 2.4.6

Tags: adminhtml, invoice, pdf, magento2.4.6, mail

I would like to attach the invoice PDF to the custom email. I have searched through several links on Stack Exchange, but unfortunately, I have not been able to make any progress on this issue.

I hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: So you want to send generated PDF to another custom email, right?

Comment: yes @DhirenVasoya

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2.4 How to send attachement in email?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/340415/magento-2-4-how-to-send-attachement-in-email)